# Find the value of $x$,$y$ and $z$ if $(x-4)(y-4)=16$,$(y-6)(z-6)=36$ and $(z-8)(x-8)=64$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Well it is the problem from jmo odisha. It is of 5 marks
I tried a lot of ways but I can't get the answer. Only elementary mathematics is allowed.

Comment: Welcome to math SE. What have you tried? Please edit your post to include the ways you already try.

Comment: It was my first mse post. I will try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Aos usuários de língua *portuguesa***

**Questão**: Encontre os valores "$x$", "$y$" e "$z$"
se

$\left\{\begin{array}{lcr}(x-4)(y-4)&=&16\\(y-6)(z-6)&=&36\\(z-8)(x-8)&=&64\end{array}\right.$

> Solução, por etapas:
>
> (I) A partir da terceira linha, vamos isolar(o que der) em função de "y":
>
> > $[z-8]=[(z-6)-2]\to$
> >
> > $[z-8]=\dfrac{36}{(y-6)}-2\to$
> >
> > $[z-8]=\dfrac{36-2(y-6)}{(y-6)}\to$
> >
> > $\boxed{[z-8]=\dfrac{48-2y}{y-6}}$
>
> e
>
> > $[x-8]=[(x-4)-4]\to$
> >
> > $[x-8]=\dfrac{16}{y-4}-4\to$
> >
> > $[x-8]=\dfrac{16-4(y-4)}{y-4}\to$
> >
> > $\boxed{[x-8]=\dfrac{32-4y}{y-4}}$
>
> (II) Aplicando os resultados obtidos à terceira linha, teremos:
>
> > $\dfrac{48-2y}{y-6}\cdot\dfrac{32-4y}{y-4}=64$
> >
> > Para $y\neq 6\,\,$ e $\,\,y\neq 4$, teremos:
> >
> > $2\cdot(24-y)\cdot 4\cdot(8-y)=64\cdot(y-6)\cdot(y-4)$
> >
> > $\not{8}\cdot(y^2-32y+192)=\not{6}\not{4}\cdot(y^2-10y+24)\to$
> >
> > $y^2-32y+\not{1}\not{9}\not{2}=8y^2-80y+\not{1}\not{9}\not{2}\to$
> >
> > $\boxed{7y^2-48y=0}\Rrightarrow \boxed{y=0}\checkmark\quad$ ou $\quad\boxed{y=\dfrac{48}{7}}\checkmark$
>
> (III) Aplicando os valores de "$y$" encontrados, ambos válidos,
>   vamos obter os respectivos valores de "$x$" e de "$z$"; assim:
>
> > Para $\boxed{y=0}$
> >
> > > Aplicado-o à equação $x-8=\dfrac{32-4y}{y-4}$
> > >
> > > $x-8=\dfrac{32-4\cdot 0}{0-4}\to x-8=-8\to\boxed{x=0}$
> > >
> > > Aplicando-o à equação $z-8=\dfrac{48-2y}{y-6}$
> > >
> > > $z-8=\dfrac{48-2\cdot 0}{0-6}\to z-8=-8\to\boxed{z=0}$
> > >
> > > **Aqui, a primeira terna final de solução: $(0;\,0;\,0)\checkmark$**
> >
> > Para $\boxed{y=\dfrac{48}{7}}$
> >
> > > Aplicado-o à equação $x-8=\dfrac{32-4y}{y-4}$
> > >
> > > $x-8=\dfrac{32-4\cdot\frac{48}{7}}{\frac{48}{7}-4}\to x-8=\dfrac{\frac{32}{\not{7}}}{\frac{20}{\not{7}}}\to$
> > >
> > > $x-8=\dfrac{8}{5}\to\boxed{x=\dfrac{48}{5}}$
> > >
> > > Aplicando-o à equação $z-8=\dfrac{48-2y}{y-6}$
> > >
> > > $z-8=\dfrac{48-2\cdot\frac{48}{7}}{\frac{48}{7}-6}\to z-8=\dfrac{\frac{240}{\not{7}}}{\frac{6}{\not{7}}}\to$
> > >
> > > $z-8=40\to\boxed{z=48}$
> > >
> > > **Aqui, a segunda terna final de solução:$\left(\dfrac{48}{5};\,\dfrac{48}{7};\,48\right)\checkmark$**
>
> ***É isso!!***

Answer (score 3):

An obvious solution is $x=y=z=0$, but it's not the only one: you could have
$x=48/5$, $y = 48/7$, $z=48$.

Take $(z-6)$ times equation 1 minus $(x-4)$ times equation 2 and simplify to eliminate $y$: you should get 
$$ (2 z+24) x - 24 z = 0 $$

Take $(2z+24)$ times equation 3 minus $(z-8)$ times this equation and simplify to eliminate $x$: you should get 
$$ 8 z^2 - 384 z = 0$$
which factors as $8 z (z - 48) = 0$.  So $z = 0$ or $z = 48$.  Substitute into other equations to find $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$x-4=\frac {16}{y-4}; z-6=\frac {36}{y-6}$$ so that $$(x-8)(z-8)=\left(\frac {16}{y-4}-4\right)\left(\frac {36}{y-6}-2\right)=64$$ and clearing fractions this gives $$(32-4y)(48-2y)=64(y-4)(y-6)$$

This is a quadratic, which simplifies somewhat: roots are $y=0, y=\frac {48}7$

You can check easily that there are no solutions $y=4$ or $y=6$ so that no division by zero is concealed here.